# Get parameter passed in URL Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, uri

Basically I have an anchor tag (update) that gets the id of the request in the table and load the update view getting all the request details

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('dashboard/staff/request/update_request_view/'.$drafts['idx']);?>" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-info update-button <?php if($drafts['status']=='ONGOING'){echo 'disableClick';}?>"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Update</a>
```

This is then received in my method

```
public function update_request_view($idx)
{
   //some code here to load the view and get details
}
```

The url then becomes `http://localhost/dashboard/staff/request/update_request_view/48`

Now when I try to save the update that I make using another method

```
public function update()
{
     $idx = $this->uri->segment(5);
}
```

My `$idx` variable is empty. When I use `$this->uri->segment(4)`, I get update_request_view.

I dont wanna use hidden fields since it will cause lots of security issues and also when I will be able to work this out i will encrypt the id. Why is my `$this->uri->segment(5)` empty and how do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, if I understand you correctly, it is because the `update` function is a separate page than `http://localhost/dashboard/staff/request/update_request_view/48`. So CI doesn't see any of the previous url variables. You can either submit to `update/{$id}` (action url) or you *can* use a hidden field; it is no less safer than using an id in the url as that can be just as easily manipulated with a change to the form action.

That being said, if you are really concerned about security you should restrict access to particular users for a given record using some sort of ACL.

Comment: Thanks, yes I read some stuff and found answers like what you said. Thank you for your help mate